# Union containing Enum values

Tags: typescript

`SupportedParameter` is a union of supported `Parameter` enum values. When providing values for `details` array I get this error.

> Types of property 'parameter' are incompatible.
> Type 'Parameter' is not assignable to type 'SupportedParameter'.

I understand `Parameter.ONE`/`Parameter.THREE` aren't exactly `SupportedParameter` but they are part of it. What can I do to satisfy `details` type? I could do `Parameter.ONE as SupportedParameter` but that's just getting rid of the error, not solving the problem.

Argument `parameter` passed into `isParameterEnabled` also complains about it being a `Parameter` and not `SupportedParameter` even though all parameter properties in details are part of `SupportedParameter`.

```
enum Parameter {
  ONE = 'ONE',
  TWO = 'TWO',
  THREE = 'THREE'
}

type SupportedParameter = Parameter.ONE | Parameter.THREE;

type Detail = { label: string; };

const parametersConfig: Record<SupportedParameter, { enabled: boolean }> = {
  [Parameter.ONE]: {enabled: true},
  [Parameter.THREE]: {enabled: false},
}

const isParameterEnabled = (parameter: SupportedParameter) => {
  return parametersConfig[parameter].enabled;
}

const details: {label: string; parameter: SupportedParameter }[] = [{
  label: 'One',
  parameter: Parameter.ONE,
}, {
  label: 'Three',
  parameter: Parameter.THREE
}].filter(({ parameter }) => isParameterEnabled(parameter));
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACghgJzhYAXYCoG8CwAoKKAeQDkBRKAXigHJSyaAafQgFQHUiraOimWorABIAlMhWo1hYhvgC%20%20fKgCeAB2BQAymFWqA9gnQATeEhTpM1U8jQYAdPSgAfWIhsW708QG5FeFepQACJocACWADbcWFARcABGwBEAXFAAzqgIYSAA5t5Qcr54%20ADGeiAZUKpu5hhpAMLlAGZhOakiwGUIRgA82roGxta1CIzYUKAJEcBGqfF6etNwIAUAfNECANrDtggO5AC6qViT8dOzUJlgwHLMBFDbNbueouJH2KfnqU1wEWk3dwUxTwZQqqCgYTSOwsZBAUxm3AAFNUzLtUv19IYZtCMABKKjrXD3BBoMAIFYo9x1RogFo5TaUkYHOyfGZFIGlcqVIyhSJpY5xRIpdKZbJ5KpPCzonSYoaSjAFTYHbibImEQVJVJ0EDAfj3Rlo1yojz0QFjNWxBKangACxJuruhANUqNVL2XjI8mZLQiFkRiJizoVcnxlHWkJxCFh8KMyPlCFxuKK%20CAA)

Comment: That is really weird because it works just fine if you don't chain the `filter` right after the assignment... `const a = details.filter(({ parameter }) => isParameterEnabled(parameter))`

Comment: @MikeS. exactly, if you don't filter, you also don't get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preface: This should go without saying, but the compiler does not have human-level intelligence and cannot simply "see" the intent of the developer.  It follows a set of heuristics and other fixed rules, and any benefit it would get of adding another rule or type of rule needs to outweigh the performance penalty of following such a new rule in all the cases in which it doesn't help.  There's always going to be code that looks obvious to a human being that the compiler has trouble with, until we reach the [singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity).

---

Let's pare this example down to the bare minimum:

```
const foo: SupportedParameter[] = [Parameter.ONE]; // okay
const bar: SupportedParameter[] = [Parameter.ONE].filter(x => x) // error
```

This is a limitation of TypeScript's type inference.  When the type checker sees the value `Parameter.ONE`, it needs to decide what type it should infer for that value.  Is it just the very specific type `Parameter.ONE`?  Or the full enum type `Parameter`?  Or something wider like `string` or `unknown`?  The heuristic rule that is used in general for an enum value is that the full enum type `Parameter` is inferred unless there is some hint to do something else.

The reason why `foo` above works is because TypeScript can use [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) to interpret the array literal `[Parameter.ONE]` as conforming to `SupportedParameter[]`.  It sort of acts "backwards" (at runtime the array  literal is created first and then assigned to the variable, but contextual typing infers the type of the array literal from the expected type of the variable) and has to reach inside `[Parameter.ONE]` to `Parameter.ONE` and interpret it as a narrower type than the default inferred type of `Parameter`.

Contextual typing has its limits, though... it doesn't work backwards through an arbitrary number of statements or nested expressions.  This would be implausible in general, since it would be prohibitively expensive to propagate inferences very far, and it would generate lots of partial/generic/candidate inferences depending on how far it decided to propagate.  Consider the `bar` example.  In order for that to compile, the compiler would need to look at `[Parameter.ONE].filter(x => x)` and say that whatever that `filter()` method is, it must return a `SupportedParameter[]`.  But what is that `filter()` method?  Well, it's a method of `[Parameter.ONE]`, which is some array literal.  So it's some array type, but which type?  We don't know yet. The compiler would need to either start making guesses ("Maybe it's `Parameter[]`?  No, that fails. Should I widen it?  Maybe `unknown[]`? No, that still fails.  Narrow it to `Parameter.ONE[]`? Okay, that works) or do some higher order reasoning about arrays (okay, this is an array of some generic type `T[]`, and therefore the `filter()` method, [defined as having two overloaded call signatures](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/481357a4c83206591091b9b88016e208e3959fce/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1367-L1373) could either return `S[]` for some `S extends T` or else it would return `T[]`, and since we want that to be `SupportedParameter[]`, then `T` needs to be assignable to `SupportedParameter` if we use the second overload, or something else if we use the first overload, so therefore ...).  Either way that's a lot of extra processing that, most of the time, would be completely useless.

So what happens instead? The compiler just does the normal inference.  The type of `[Parameter.ONE]` is inferred as `Parameter[]`, and then the `filter()` method returns `Parameter[]`, and then there's an error.

---

The fix here is to just tell the compiler to interpret `Parameter.ONE` more narrowly when you first use it.  The easiest way to do this is via a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), `Parameter.ONE as const`.  That tells the compiler that you want the most specific inference it can make, which will just be the literal type `Parameter.ONE`.  Then things just work:

```
const baz: SupportedParameter[] = [Parameter.ONE as const].filter(x => x) // okay again
```

Your more complex example also works if you do this:

```
const details: { label: string; parameter: SupportedParameter }[] = [{
  label: 'One',
  parameter: Parameter.ONE as const,
}, {
  label: 'Three',
  parameter: Parameter.THREE as const
}].filter(({ parameter }) => isParameterEnabled(parameter));
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACghgJzhYAXYCoG8CwAoKKAeQDkBRKAXigHJSyaAafQgFQHUiraOimWorABIAlMhWo1hYhvgC++fKgCeAB2BQAymFWqA9gnQATeEhTpM1U8jQYAdPSgAfWIhsW708QG5FeAMZ6IADOqFAAZnp6AFxaOvqGwCZu5hgA2gC63GnWqQgO5BneUAD0JVB6ANZwyviBIWEARoix2roGxrm2CJnZXR70GXbhAJYANhYAFAAeVAB8UNMAlKXlGAgGdUGhUM0AXq3xHUn96VnUOSndBRRwwVD1oUOjExgz84srZRXVylBwAHM4CMQH4-Cp1FAACJoYFjbhYKBjOCNYBjWKhBAggHFOS+PBbBpQVRXCzBADCQVGANiImAgQQRgAPG0Ep1SRhGNgoKAUWMkrFGlF+XAQFA5AtqLgCFBLmZroNYojeY1+UZYqgEGANHJmDK5e57F4yBklTyQHyBRE4GNgjq9QoCQFtmERsFTggyBbVUluJMSfKLId2olkoGMCtKAtpYQEGgwAgxQHDQgKVSRgC0sm8kMVWr8Y7CTsjLDxsEzcjUeioJjscVs91g2yThzMHJehcY0iUWjYnQQMB+DKG0HXOH8o47g8XQ6uV3K72eAALOODvWEEcYWIezyicT-e6PVDyZ7jKaTRGbtuRhZuj1ey1Gf2tpZLfF+IA)

Comment: Is TS documented down to this level of detail somewhere? Or do I have to understand the source code to find this kind of answer, if you're not currently online?

Comment: I rarely look at or fully understand the TS source code.  Mostly my info comes from the TS Handbook, release notes, and GitHub issues... plus a lot of trial and error.  There's an outdated TS language spec document, but that's becoming increasingly useless.  I don't think there's any single master document that would give you the detail you're looking for, unfortunately.  The language is still being developed too quickly for that kind of book to be properly maintained.